# How to Read one file and generating multiple text output file

Tags: java, io

I hava a one text file like below. My question is I want to read my txt file upto each one paragraph and generating separate new text file for each one on java

> ```
> >T0646 OR188, , 93 residues
> MQEERKKLLEKLEKILDEVTDGAPDEARERIEKLAKDVKDELEEGDAKNMIEKFRDEMEQ
> MYKDAPNAVMEQLLEEIEKLLKKAGSLVPRGSY
>
>
> >T0647 HR5514A, , 157 residues
> MTERLSAEQIKEYKGVFEMFDEEGNGEVKTGELEWLMSLLGINPTKSELASMAKDVDRDN
> KGFFFNCDGFLALMGVYHEKAQNQESELRAAFRVFDKEGKGYIDWNTLKYVLMNAGEPLN
> EVEAEQMMKEADKDGDRTIDYEEFVAMMTGESFKLIQ
>
>
> >T0648 CpN10, , 102 residues
> MAGQAFRKFLPLFDRVLVERSAAETVTKGGIMLPEKSQGKVLQATVVAVGSGSKGKGGEI
> QPVSVKVGDKVLLPEYGGTKVVLDDKDYFLFRDGDILGKYVD
> ```

---

```
public class Test{

    public static void main (String[] args){          
        BufferedReader br=null;
        BufferedWriter bw= null;

        File file = new File("...Desktop\\New folder\\out.txt");
        try {
            String s;
            String text = "";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "....Desktop\\New folder\\casp10.txt"));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            while ((s=br.readLine())!= null) {
                if(s.contains(">")){
                    String line=br.readLine();
                    if(line!=null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        bw.write('\n'+ line );
                    }
                }
                bw.write(s +"\n");
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br!=null) {
                    br.close();
                    bw.close();
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Create a new writer pointing to a different file when you reach a boundary.

Comment: you're writing the > (in variable s) after writing the next line, so you're reordering the output compared to the input.

Comment: So what changes should I made in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invokes this every time you want to print with a different Writer

```
    public class MySaver{
    private PrintWriter innerWriter;
    public MySaver(Writer writer)
    {
    this.innerWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
    }

    public void save(String c) throws IOException {
        innerWriter.write(c);
    }

}
```

Or first create string with StringBuilder and append would you like and then print its. [String Builder Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to create a new `FileWriter` object in your `while` loop, everytime you see a `'>'` symbol.
I am using simple int file counter to name multiple output files viz.

> out0.txt, out1.txt, out2.txt and so on.

See below the working code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileWriting{

    public static void main (String[] args){          
        BufferedReader br=null;
        BufferedWriter bw= null;

        String outFileName = "D:\\New folder\\out";
        try {
            String s;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\New folder\\casp10.txt"));
            int fileCounter = 0;

            while ((s=br.readLine())!= null) {
                if(s.contains(">")){
                    if(bw != null){
                        bw.close();
                    }
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outFileName + (fileCounter++) + ".txt");
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                }
                bw.write(s +"\n");
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br!=null) {
                    br.close();
                    bw.close();
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got my exact output. I really appreciate your effort